# What is the best practice for password input in payment webpage?

Tags: security, passwords, payment, user-experience

In China, B2C/C2C websites like taobao.com, alipay.com require to install ActiveX or such kind of Controls for password input field in login and payment pages.  Their official reason is to anti-keylogger and encrypt the password(it has SSL as well).

But Controls may provide more terrible user experience. Like in Chrome, we can not "Tab" into Controls to key in the password after key in the account name. And due to permission issue it is not allow to "Enter" to post account&password in Controls. And meanwhile the Controls may have phishing risk if Controls in user's PC were hacked.

I notice B2C/C2C websites like ebay, paypal, amazon in world-wide do not require to install any Controls. Sometimes even not to provide virtual keyboard for password key in. 
So is the anti-keylogger one of factors have to consider in a payment web design? What is the best practice for password input in payment site to balance security and user experience?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a virtual onscreen keyboard with JavaScript.

Comment: hmm, one of concerns for virtual keyboard solution, it must require Users not in a public place around to avoid spy.